# Laravel auto update a field in the table

Tags: php, laravel

I have a table named `task` that has the columns `end_time`(datetime) and `status`(int) with multiple rows. For those rows where the `end_time` is greater than the current time, I want to change the status value. Therefore, the status column value will be updated when the `end_time` of a row exceeds the current time value. If multiple rows meet the conditions, it will update several rows.

The process needs to be automatic. In a Laravel project, what is the best method to go about doing that?

NB: I'm somewhat familiar with laravel task scheduling, but also want to make sure that it's the best approach.

Comment: It depends on if you want it automatic when the record is saved, or periodically. You can create a command to update the records, and add it to the scheduler. https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#main-content

Comment: *"that it's the best approach."* - Best is a subjective term. Try out some solutions, like on modification of a `Task` record, or via a scheduler, etc., and see which one best fits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

There are some approaches to this that depends on your need.

**Task Scheduling**

If you need this field updated on your database, scheduled tasks is a good aproach. You can create a [artisan command](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/artisan#writing-commands) to do this. Your command would do something like this:

```php
Task::whereDate('end_time', '<', now())
  ->whereNot('status', 'due')
  ->update(['status' => 'due']);
```

Finally, you can set the command to be run at certain moments of the day using [task scheduling](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#scheduling-artisan-commands).

Remember that only configuring the scheduled task is not enough. You need to configure your server to [run the Laravel Scheduler](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/scheduling#running-the-scheduler).

**Data Reader**

If you don't need the field to be updated on the database, but only be shown to the user as `due`, you can create an [accessor function](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) for this field in order to show it as you want.